# SWRevealViewController dismiss correctly to navigate to next storyboard?

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, dismiss

I have 2 storyboard *login.storyboard* and *main.storybard*. On the *main.storyboard I use the [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController). In the sidebarmenu of the SWRevealViewController I have a logout function, which do the logout and redirect to the *login.storyboard*. By doing this I get the warning:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <LoginViewController: 0x1551a630>  on <SidePanelViewController: 0x15645110> which is already presenting (null)
```

I think the SidePanelViewController (which is the SWRevealViewController) is not dissmissed correctly.

**How do I do this exactly, to avoid this issue?**

#### SidePanelViewController.h

```c
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SingletonClass.h"

@interface SidePanelViewController : UITableViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) SingletonClass *sshare;

@end
```

#### SidePanelViewController.m

```c
#import "SidePanelViewController.h"
#import "SWRevealViewController.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface SidePanelViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *menuItems;

@end

@implementation SidePanelViewController

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
        DLog(@"inited");
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.sshare = [SingletonClass sharedInstance];
    self.menuItems = @[@"toSurroundStream", @"toImprint", @"logout"];
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.menuItems count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *CellIdentifier = [self getCellName:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    if (indexPath.row == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@'s Stream", self.sshare.username];
    }

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)getCellName:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSAssert(self.menuItems, @"menuItems is missing");

    NSString *cellName = @"nix";

    if (indexPath.row < self.menuItems.count) {
        cellName = self.menuItems[indexPath.row];
    }

    DLog(@"cellName: %@", cellName);
    NSAssert(![cellName isEqualToString:@"nix"], @"No cellIdentifier found, check your menuLists. Consider IB as well");

    return cellName;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSAssert(self.menuItems, @"Array with menuItems does not exist");

    if (indexPath.item < self.menuItems.count) {
        NSString *cellName = [self getCellName:indexPath];

        DLog(@"cellName %@ call a method", cellName);

        if ([cellName isEqualToString:@"logout"]) {
            [self logout];
        }

-(void)logout {
    DLog(@"doing the logout");
    [[FBSession activeSession] closeAndClearTokenInformation];
    [self toLoginView];
}


-(void)toImprint {
#warning goto Imprint has to be implemented
}

-(IBAction)toLoginView {

    UIStoryboard *loginStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *loginViewController = [loginStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    loginViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{

    if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];
        };

    }

}

@end
```

Comment: Why are you using two storyboards - would it not be simpler to have have these views in one storyboard?

Comment: different reasons: Your Storyboard get not messed up, logical seperation of parts, if more developer work on it you can split it by parts and there is no hassle merging the storyboard.

Comment: Thats an interesting approach. Never thought of it like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to work, at least I do not get the warning message again and the app works like desired.

#### SidePanelViewController.m

```c
-(IBAction)toLoginView {

    UIStoryboard *loginStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Login" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *loginViewController = [loginStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    loginViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

    // [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];
    [[self presentedViewController] dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:nil];

    [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];
}
```